# Flutter : Display Values inside GridView depending on Selected Category

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, card

I have an app that displays _customCard which is customized card inside GridView. I want to control the contents of the cards inside GridView so it could be changed according to selected value SelectedCategory of 6 different categories.

Here is where I control SelectedCategory:

```
_favouritePressed(int index){
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
```

Here is the code of GridView:

```
GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: <Widget>[
            _customCard(
              imageUrl: "assassin.png", item: "game", price: "\$50", count: 1
            ),
            _customCard(
              imageUrl: "sedan.png", item: "car", price: "\$25", count: 4
            ),
            _customCard(
              imageUrl: "blouse.png", item: "T-shirt", price: "\$20", count: 2
            ),
            _customCard(
              imageUrl: "toy.png", item: "kids", price: "\$2", count: 3
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question but I will take a shot at the solution:

```
GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: <Widget>[
        if (selectedIndex==0)
          _customCard(
            imageUrl: "assassin.png", item: "game", price: "\$50", count: 1
          ),
        if (selectedIndex==1)
          _customCard(
            imageUrl: "sedan.png", item: "car", price: "\$25", count: 4
          ),
        if (selectedIndex==2)
          _customCard(
            imageUrl: "blouse.png", item: "T-shirt", price: "\$20", count: 2
          ),
        if (selectedIndex==3)
          _customCard(
            imageUrl: "toy.png", item: "kids", price: "\$2", count: 3
          ),
      ],
    ),
```

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: First Thank you for helping.. I mean that I want the four _cusomCards details to change depending on the selection of one category

Comment: Then perhaps you should look at a function to lookup the card attributes based on the card id and the selected index.